# EEFileLoadException when running c# application as COM component from C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have a 64bit WPF application that uses third party x86 dlls. This runs fine as an exe, however when I build the application as a COM dll and run from a 64bit c++ program, I get EEFileLoadException exceptions when loading the third party dlls.

The exceptions occur during startup and if I ignore them, the program runs fine and the dlls eventually load, so this indicates to me that the dlls are in the correct location - this rules out the solutions provided to other questions.

I don't want to simply ignore them as it would be good to understand why they are occurring. I know what dlls are failing to load but can't debug why.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If I remember right, there was an issue with Visual Studio's tools being x86, so you will see these exceptions when debugging COM, even though there really isn't a problem. Is the exception unhandled and makes your process crash or does the process continue with no problem? When I did COM interop, I'd see that exception, and Windows would handle it internally. If the latter, just chalk it up to expected output while debugging. It is OK to see exceptions, as long as they are handled.

Comment: Yes, the exceptions appear to be handled and allow the application to run. Thanks for your feedback.